# Generate large number of unique random float32 numbers

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

I need to generate a binary file containing only unique random numbers, with single precision.
The purpose is then to calculate the entropy of this file and use it with other datasets entropy to calculate a ratio entropy_file/entropy_randUnique. This value is named "randomness".

I can do this in python with double-precision numbers and inserting them into `set()`, using `struct.pack` like so:

```
    numbers = set()
    while len(numbers) < size:
        numbers.add(struct.pack(precision,random.random()))
    for num in numbers:
        file.write(num)
```

but when I change to single precision I can't just change the pack method (that will produce a lot of the same numbers and the while will never end), and I can't generate single precision numbers with `random`. I've looked into `numpy` but the generator works the same way from what I understood.
How can I get 370914252 (this is my biggest test case) unique float32 inside a binary file, even if they're not random, I think that a shuffled sequence would suffice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to generate random 32-bit integers then convert them to floating point. You'll need to reject bit representations of infinity and NAN as you generate the numbers.

You can generate your `set` from the integer values rather than the floating point ones, then do the conversion on output. Rather than using a set, you could use a bit map to detect which integer values have already been used; that's more likely to fit in memory, especially given the largest sample size you indicate.

```
def random_unique_floats(n):
    used = bytearray(0 for i in xrange(2**32 // 8))
    count = 0
    while count < n:
        bits = random.getrandbits(32)
        value = struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('I', bits))[0]
        if not math.isinf(value) and not math.isnan(value):
            index = bits // 8
            mask = 0x01 << (bits & 0x07)
            if used[index] & mask == 0:
                yield value
                used[index] |= mask
                count += 1

for num in random_unique_floats(size):
    file.write(struct.pack('f', num))
```

Note that as your number of samples approaches the number of possible floating-point values, the run time will go up exponentially.

Comment: I've never used `yield`, I am trying this `for num in random_unique_floats(size): file.write(num)` which I'm not sure it is correct. It is giving an error "used = bytearray(0 for i in range(2**32 / 8))
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" 
edit: I've changed xrange to range because I'm using python3

Comment: @SamGamgee, then you need to use `2**32 // 8` to get integer division. I'll edit the answer. I'm leaving the `xrange` as is though so the answer still works for Python 2.

Comment: Ok that makes sense (also thank you for teaching me the // division :)) I am running the program now with increasing samples, so far it appears to be working correctly! Will mark as the answer soon.